# How to run a function in turtle from python 3

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am creating an art show with turtle graphics. This is what I have. I am able to run the code by separately entering in each line. Each separate chunk of code draws one item (sky, flower, grass, etc.) How can I put all of this into one function that will run? Or is that not possible?

```
from turtle import *

def art_show():
    speed(30)
    penup()
    goto(-100,160)
    pensize(30)
    pencolor('deep sky blue')
    pendown()
    fd(500)
    penup()
    goto(-100,175)
    pendown()
    fd(500)
    penup()
    goto(-100,190)
    pendown()
    fd(500)

    penup()
    goto(60,170)
    pencolor('yellow')
    pendown()
    circle(10)

    penup()
    goto(-100,-100)
    pencolor('forest green')
    pendown()
    fd(500)
    penup()
    goto(-100,-85)
    pendown()
    fd(500)
    penup()
    goto(-100,-70)
    pendown()
    fd(500)

    penup()
    goto(-75,-75)
    pendown()
    pensize(3)
    pencolor('dark green')
    lt(90)
    fd(100)
    penup()
    goto(-40,-90)
    pendown()
    fd(200)

    penup()
    goto(-75, 25)
    pendown()

    for i in range(6):
        pencolor("slateblue")
        circle(25)
        lt(60)

    for i in range(6):
        pencolor('dodgerblue')
        circle(15)
        lt(60)

    for i in range(6):
        pencolor('deeppink')
        circle(5)
        lt(60)

    penup()
    goto(-40, 110)
    pendown()

    for i in range(6):
        pencolor("red")
        circle(25)
        lt(60)

    for i in range(6):
        pencolor('pink')
        circle(15)
        lt(60)

    for i in range(6):
        pencolor('yellow')
        circle(5)
        lt(60)


    penup()
    goto(20,-60)
    pencolor('brown')
    pendown()
    rt(90)
    fd(140)
    lt(90)
    fd(100)
    lt(45)
    fd(100)
    lt(90)
    fd(100)
    lt(45)
    fd(100)

    penup()
    goto(20, 40)
    pendown()
    lt(90)
    fd(140)
    penup()
    goto(70,-60)
    pendown()
    lt(90)
    pencolor('black')
    fd(45)
    rt(90)
    fd(30)
    rt(90)
    fd(45)
```

Comment: This should work. Just call `art_show()`.

Answer (score 0):

just add:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    art_show()
```

to the bottom of your file.  Then it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to call `art_show()` after you define `art_show()`.  Below is a rework of your code to simplify it some and address some coding style issues:

```
from turtle import *

def jump(x, y):
    penup()
    goto(x, y)
    pendown()

def art_show():
    pensize(30)
    pencolor('deep sky blue')  # sky
    jump(-100, 160)
    fd(500)
    jump(400, 175)
    bk(500)
    jump(-100, 190)
    fd(500)

    pencolor('yellow')  # sun
    jump(60, 170)
    circle(10)

    pencolor('forest green')  # lawn
    jump(-100, -100)
    fd(500)
    jump(400, -85)
    bk(500)
    jump(-100, -70)
    fd(500)

    pensize(3)
    pencolor('dark green')  # stems
    jump(-75, -75)
    lt(90)
    fd(100)
    jump(-40, -90)
    fd(200)

    pencolor("slateblue")  # left flower
    jump(-75, 25)

    for _ in range(6):
        circle(25)
        lt(60)

    pencolor('dodgerblue')

    for _ in range(6):
        circle(15)
        lt(60)

    pencolor('deeppink')

    for _ in range(6):
        circle(5)
        lt(60)

    pencolor("red")  # right flower
    jump(-40, 110)

    for _ in range(6):
        circle(25)
        lt(60)

    pencolor('pink')

    for _ in range(6):
        circle(15)
        lt(60)

    pencolor('yellow')

    for _ in range(6):
        circle(5)
        lt(60)

    pencolor('brown')  # house
    jump(20, -60)
    rt(90)
    fd(140)

    for _ in range(2):
        lt(90)
        fd(100)
        lt(45)
        fd(100)

    jump(20, 40)
    lt(90)
    fd(140)

    pencolor('black')  # door
    jump(70, -60)
    lt(90)
    fd(45)
    rt(90)
    fd(30)
    rt(90)
    fd(45)

speed('fastest')  # if number, only 0 - 10 make sense

art_show()

hideturtle()

mainloop()
```